# How to apply git patch properly after switching branches?

Tags: git

I am trying to create a diff & apply a patch. For that I have created a blank text file & committed it, now I am adding "Hello world" in the text file & committing it. Using the `git diff` command I can see the diff as:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/New Text Document.txt b/New Text Document.txt
index e69de29..b0a6290 100644
--- a/New Text Document.txt
+++ b/New Text Document.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+Helo world
\ No newline at end of file
```

Now I am creating patch with the command `git diff >first.patch`. The file gets created, now I am switching to another branch using `git checkout -b dummy` & here if I try to apply the patch with the below command I get the error as shown. What's wrong?

```
git apply first.patch
error: patch failed: New Text Document.txt:0
error: New Text Document.txt: patch does not apply
```

Comment: `git checkout -b dummy` keeps the content of files on disk as is. For example: your `New Text Document.txt` file still contains its "Hello world" line, when the patch expects an empty file. Did you reset the content of your files on disk, to match the starting state expected by your patch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you created a patch which adds a "Hello world" line to an empty file.

When you run `git checkout -b dummy`, you create a new branch, but this command does not change the content of files on disk. So `New Text Document.txt` still has its "Hello world" line, instead of being empty.

Therefore : when you run `git apply first.patch`, it fails because `New Text Document.txt` isn't empty.

---

To test on your current repo : just run `git checkout "New Text Document.txt"`, to reset its content to the starting state expected by your patch.